# rails 3 warden NameError (uncaught throw `warden'):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, warden

this is how it should work:
I log in to the admin panel, go to cars/new and fill up the fields, press create and I should have a new car in my list. [www.autozeep.com](http://autozeep.com)

the thing is that it goes ok until I press the Create button to create the new car, server logs shows this:

```
NameError (uncaught throw `warden'):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `login_required'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:17:in `call'
```

in the development mode this is working fine, on the server in production mode it's not, it's the same code, nothing changed.
for more server logs: http://pastie.org/3028350

```
application_controller

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

  # filter

  def login_required
    return true if authenticated?
    warden.authenticate!
  end
```

users_controller: http://pastie.org/3028586

I can edit a car, it works fine so the update and edit functions from cars_controller are ok, I checked the new and create functions from cars_controller but I couldn't fine anything that would give me an idea of what is going on. Cars_controller:  http://pastie.org/3028452

Please help, I have this app allready running and the client si waiting for this problem only to be solved. Thank you all very much.

**EDIT**

```
NameError in CarsController#create

uncaught throw `warden'

Rails.root: /u/apps/zeepauto/releases/20111123173432
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `login_required'
app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:17:in `call'

ENV DUMP
...
....
rack.url_scheme: "http"
rack.version: [1, 0]
warden: Warden::Proxy:-621456458 @config={:default_strategies=>{:_all=>[:database]}, :failure_app=>UsersController, :default_scope=>:default, :scope_defaults=>{}, :intercept_401=>true}
warden.options: {:attempted_path=>"/cars", :action=>"unauthenticated"}
```

I get this errors only when I add new car, I can edit cars, news, contacts. everything except cars.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

This problem was caused by some jquery library, I am using dynamic_form in this form so when I select car name in the next select_box appears only models for the selected car. Inspecting the problem (with my teacher, I wouldn't think of it by myself) we see that when I select car, a process called "dynamic_carmodels" is running in the logs to update the carmodels list and also at this point the session key is changed by another one, normally if session key is changed, the session that I started when I logged in is not valid anymore and that's why I get an "unauthenticated error". Still have no idea what jquery exactly was causing the problem but finally I got this solved, this was not because of the warden configuration.

Comment: it's in https://github.com/rmagnum2002/zeepauto

Comment: Seems like its a dependency on rails_warden, it should be picked up by bundler but try it.

Comment: thanks, I am trying it now. I am talking with the support staff to try what you sugest.

Comment: I would really recommend using Devise if you're looking at Warden, it removes so many problems...

Comment: Warden is fine, he just never configured properly. Devise needs even more work

Comment: Daniel, could I contact you via skype or any other messaneger software to finish this thing faster. Please, I would give out all my points for this :)

Comment: just wrote you a detailed explanation of the problem. If you understand why is happening fixing it should be easy.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow and I'll get with an answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I will explain to you why this exception is happening very carefully but I can't fix it for you.

Warden guards your application with a catch(:warden) block, you can see this in:

```
# Invoke the application guarding for throw :warden.
# If this is downstream from another warden instance, don't do anything.
# :api: private
def call(env) # :nodoc:
  return @app.call(env) if env['warden'] && env['warden'].manager != self

  env['warden'] = Proxy.new(env, self)
  result = catch(:warden) do
      @app.call(env)
  end
```

Your application gets called in @app.call(env) and if your application throws(:warden) it gets caught. this is how throw, catch works, here is an example:

```
def authenticate!()
  throw :warden
end

catch(:warden) do
  puts "Calling authenticate!" 
  authenticate!() 
end

puts "Succesfully called authenticate!"
#outside of catch(:) guard
authenticate!()
puts "this never gets executed"
```

If I execute this it will do:

```
 ruby exc.rb 
 Calling authenticate!
 Succesfully called authenticate!
 exc.rb:2:in `throw': uncaught throw :warden (ArgumentError)
    from exc.rb:2:in `initialize!'
    from exc.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

As you can see, the 2nd time I called authenticate! I was outside the catch(:warden) block, therefore when I throw :warden there was no catch block to catch it, exception ocurred.

This is what is happening to you, look at `warden#authenticate!`:

```
def authenticate!(*args)
   user, opts = _perform_authentication(*args)
   throw(:warden, opts) unless user
   user
end
```

See the throw(:warden, opts) ? If that throw is outside the catch(:warden) block the exception is raised. Warden is supposed to guard your whole app in the catch block, so that you can throw :warden at any point. But for some reason this is not happening on zeepauto.

Your problem is that warden is not properly setup(there is no `config/initializers/warden.rb`) and `call (env)`so your catch(:warden) guard is never set.

Your answer is here: https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Setup

Just work yourself through the setup. You can test on your dev environment by throwing a :warden at any time. Just write a test like:

```
it "warden should catch the throw :warden at any point" do
  throw(:warden)
end
```

If you want to get this thing faster, just get a pro account in railscasts.com and watch: http://railscasts.com/episodes/305-authentication-with-warden that episode will guide you through the setup.

Comment: I have the manager.rb and the code in the app on the server, a copy of it is here https://github.com/rmagnum2002/zeepauto/blob/master/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails_warden-0.5.6/lib/rails_warden/manager.rb
but what about the backtrace code? where should I put it?

Comment: I mean just replace warden.authenticate! with that code, so we can log the backtrace messages.

Comment: sorry, you mean here  https://github.com/rmagnum2002/zeepauto/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb ? warden.authenticate! to replace with backtrace code? I haven't used such tricks before and I don't know how to make it right.

Comment: Its just wrapping the call that throws(:warden) to catch the NameError exception and then using the exception handler to backtrace. I made a mistake on the pull request, remove the duplicate code.

Comment: could you write please write a more detailed tutorial on this sollution? I really have no idea (and the support staff too) where to put this code and what it should lool like, if you'd be so kind to pull this out please.

Comment: http://pastie.org/3038504
here is the server logs that I recieved from support staff
could be this of any help to see where the problem is?

Comment: @search is nil at some point, you have a nil pointer where you did not expect it. In your controller when you do Car.search(params[:search]) this is returning nil, and you never check

Comment: Ok I looked at your app, you did not configured warden at all, read the docs...you need some sort of handler when authentication fail and you need to tell that to warden

Comment: If so how can be explained the fact that I can add news and do everything else in admin side except adding cars. It's the same login_required filter to news and cars. I agree that I didn't configure the warden right but I expected at least this to work as it was on my development pc.

Comment: well I don't know perhaps you were already authenticated or something so that warden never had to call the failed app. It doesn't matter, configure it correctly and it should work

Comment: Hi Daniel: When using rails_warden, are you saying that the initializer for Warden::Manager is not required? I have been using the RailsWarden::Manager block you have above but I keep getting "uncaught throw :warden" exceptions.

Comment: @daniel: unfortunately I still get the exceptions. Incidentally, aren't you serializing the entire record class there? I had to change mine to record.class.name.

Comment: Daniel, could I contact you via skype or any other messaneger software to finish this thing faster. Please, I would give out all my points for this

Comment: See the edited question, this was not a warden issue, well it was because the session key was changed by some js library while I was filling up the form. Thank you for your time and trying to help.