# Ruby on Rails uncaught throw :warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

```
require 'test_helper'

class DashboardControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

I included Warden::Test::Helpers as directed to by other stack posts but I'm still getting the uncaught throw :warden and it's driving me crazy.  Save me? :[

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8555444/429758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah my crisis was averted by merely creating a user within the test instead of using fixtures

```
  describe "user does something" do
    it "allows users to do something" do
      User.create!(email: "example@user.com", password: "abcdef", first_name: 'Jim', last_name: 'Bo', username: 'somename')
```

I put the code above before raising any expectations and everything was fine.  For some reason when I was testing a user with the automatically generated tests and fixtures the uncaught throw :warden was raised

```
class StudentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @student = students(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:students)
  end
end
```

The above being an example of a basic test that would fail and the below being an example of a fixture I used something like below

```
one:
  first_name: User
  last_name: Example
  email: example@user.com
  password: abcdef
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, 'lalala') %>
```